# Flush the session in Grails 4.0.1

Tags: hibernate, grails, flush, hibernate-5.x, grails-4

In past projects which were using previous versions of Grails/Hibernate I have used in services funciton:

```
private void cleanGorm() {
    def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
    session.flush()
    session.clear()
}
```

and for example during long tasks like bulk updates I have used it e.g.:

```
    bigListToIterate.each {

        if (it.id > 0 && it.id % 50 == 0) {
            cleanGorm()
        }
        //CRUD action
    }
```

However this is not working for Grails 4.0.1; athough no exception is thrown, the changes are still not reflected in the db.

How can I get it done?

I'm using:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.0.Final"
```

Mysql version:

```
SELECT version();
'5.7.21'
```

If I inspect database, I can see that number of Rows in the table is increasing and Data Length of the table is increasing, however when I run MySQL query `select * from table` I can not get any results until the whole function has ended.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do some sort of batch-processing with your domain object, the standard way would be to call `.save( flush:true )` each `n` times:

```
bigListToIterate.eachWithIndex { something, index ->
    Book b = new Book(...)
    //CRUD action
    b.save flush:index > 0 && index % 50 == 0
}
```

That would flush session for you.

Comment: see update. you have to flush upon `index` instead of `id` of course

Comment: I have tried it but still without luck. Unfortunatelly it's still behaving the same way: no data is persisted in db until the whole loop has finished.

Comment: add someting like `prinltn Book.count()` right after session flush. For fun you can also do some `sleep 100`

Comment: `prinltn Book.count()` shows correct number. however it's not reflected in db

Comment: that means rather that your db-ciient is laggy